# Double redirection test

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, dash-shell

What does this print your shell?

```
echo foo | while read line; do echo $line; done < <(echo bar)
```

I would expect it to evaluate to `echo foo | bar` or `foo < <(bar)`, both of which would result in an error message.

In Bash 4.1.5 it looks like the pipe is simply discarded:

```
bar
```

In Dash:

```
sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: Why does it matter? It is bad design, you shouldn't redirect standard input more than once.

Comment: It was more of a mental exercise - I just realized that it was valid syntax, and that it should do something "reasonable" with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dash doesn't support process substitution (`<()`).

The behavior you're seeing is consistent if you use syntax that's supported by each of the shells you're comparing. Try this:

```
echo hello | cat < inputfile
```

You should see the contents of "inputfile" and not "hello". Of several shells I tried, only Z shell showed both.

This is what POSIX says regarding pipelines and redirection:

> The standard output of command1 shall be connected to the standard input of command2. The standard input, standard output, or both of a command shall be considered to be assigned by the pipeline before any redirection specified by redirection operators that are part of the command (see Redirection ).

I interpret this to mean that in the case of the example above, the pipeline assigns stdin to `cat` then the redirection overrides it.